# Flatlist not scrollable when inside KeyboardAvoidingView

Tags: android, react-native

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={Styles.container}>
    <FlatList
      data={this.props.data}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    />
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

I have a flatlist inside `KeyboardAvoidingView`. But it won't scroll on android. It works fine on ios, but not on android. I have been searching online and I can see that this component has issues on android. But I haven't been able to find mention of this specific issue. If anyone could shed some light on this issue. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced your issue but it works fine for me. What is the styling on the KeyboardAvoidingView? I haven't attached any styling yet.

Example:

```
import Rect from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, KeyboardAvoidingView, Keyboard, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default class TempView extends React.Component {
    public render() {
        return (
            <View style={ styles.view }>
                <KeyboardAvoidingView>
                    <FlatList
                        data={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]}
                        renderItem={ ( item ) => {
                            return (
                                <View 
                                    key={ item.index }
                                    style={ styles.item }>
                                    <Text>{ `Item ${ item.index + 1}`}</Text>
                                </View>
                            );
                        }}
                        />
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    view: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        paddingTop: 6
    },
    item: {
        padding: 20,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: "black"
    }
});
```